# Read Parquet files Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

We have a folder structure as below

```
fld/fld1/fld2/nm3
fld/fld1/fld2/nm4
```

nm3, nm4 folders have the parquet files. We have a situation where nm3 has a parquet file but its empty. So when we run the read.parquet we are getting only nm4. We want to retain nm3 too since it is important for logging purpose. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: How are you reading the files? Is it `spark.read.parquet("/fld/fld1/fld2/*")` or other way?
And what do you mean with "retain" nm3, since the file is empty, your read will still contain all data? What do you do in a normal scenario, if both files would have data in it, do you log the files you read or...?

Comment: I am reading the root folder in this case ```/fld```. there is a requirement to get all the folder info so I should see nm3 with 0/ null value and nm4 with whatever the count for the folder. With the read option I am not getting nm3 since the parquet is empty. Maybe thats how the parquet read would work!

Comment: Could you check out the answer below and accept if it was helpful to you? If that was not what you were looking for, could you clarify some more?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of files by using some functions from the `org.apache.hadoop` packages. You'll probably need a recursive function to go over all directories in a certain "root" folder of your choosing ("/fld") for example and filter out the ones you want (those who are empty, those who contain files ...) based on your requirement

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}


val conf = new Configuration()
val folder = new Path("/fld")
val fs = FileSystem.get(folder.toUri, conf)
val status = fs.listStatus(folder)

// you can use this status object to filter out files in your current
val files = status.filter(!_.isDirectory)

// this will give you a list of all subfolders of your current path
val subFolders = status.filter(_.isDirectory).map(_.getPath)


// putting those things in a function and calling it recursively 
// you can loop you through all folders and subfolders of you starting directory
// depending on your filters you can extract the relevant info you need.

def extractRecursively(folder: Path){
 val fs = FileSystem.get(folder.toUri, conf)
 val status = fs.listStatus(folder)
 val files = status.filter(!_.isDirectory)
 val subFolders = status.filter(_.isDirectory).map(_.getPath)
 files ++ subFolders.flatMap(f => extractRecursively(f))
}

// as an example: this function will loop through all folders and subfolders of /fld 
// and return a list of all files it encountered. 
// you can modify this function to get the names of all empty directories
// or only directories with a certain number of files...
// just check out the different filters and options of the listStatus

val allFilesInFolderAndSubfolders = extractRecursively(new Path("/fld"))
```